# Properties of a graph given a minimum degree

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying to find out some nice properties of a graph given the provided information.

Let $G$ be a simple undirected graph with $n \geq 2$ vertices and let $n \geq k$ and $δ(G) \geq \frac{n}{k}$.

What all can we say about such a graph? I'm particularly thinking of connectedness, eccentricity, and diameter which might be of interest. Any other properties and tips will be helpful too.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $k=2$, then $G$ is Hamiltonian by [Dirac's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path#Bondy%E2%80%93Chv%C3%A1tal_theorem).

Nothing can be said for the connectivity or edge connectivity in general. If $k\geq 3$, a graph with $\delta \geq \frac{n}{k}$ can be disconnected (the disjoint union of two separate complete graphs $K_n \sqcup K_n$ gives an example).

If the graph is connected, then we *can* bound the diameter.
In general, if the graph $G=(V,E)$ has order $n$, diameter $D$ and minimum degree $\delta$, then you get something that looks roughly like $3n > (D-1)(\delta + 1)$. As such, you can bound the diameter above by $D < \frac{3n}{k+1} + 1$. The proof idea is given in the spoiler.

> To get the first bound, consider a vertex $u$ with eccentricity $e(u) = D$, and let $N_i = \{v \in V : d(u,v) = i \}$. Any vertex in $N_i$ must have at least $\delta$ neighbors, and these neighbours must be in $N_{i-1}\cup N_i\cup N_{i+1}$. So for all $i$, $|N_{i-1}\cup N_i\cup N_{i+1}| \geq \delta + 1$. The bound follows from some triple-counting.